# Stack around variable 'inputValue' corrupted

Tags: c++, stack, corrupt

I have some code pasted [here](http://codepad.org/QEV9vHUq) that keeps giving me the error in the title whenever more than one number is given as input. I cannot find one place where inputValue is being improperly accessed, but I could use another (few) sets of eyes. Thanks for any help ahead of time!

```
// descriptions of declared functions listed with implementation
int ProcessInput(const int fromBase, const int toBase, char inputValue[],
                 const int length);

void ConvertToBase(int decimal, const int inBase, char outPut[]);

double Exponent(const int number, const int exponent);

int main(int argsc, char** argsv)
{
    int fromBase(0), toBase(0);

    // set bases and initialize vector for storing output until end of input
    fromBase = atoi(argsv[1]);
    toBase = atoi(argsv[2]);
    vector <char *> outPutValues;
    int count(0);

    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        // array to hold input value
        char inputValue[8] = {' '};

        // receive input from keyboard and convert input to decimal and new base
        while (cin >> inputValue)
        {
            int length(strlen(inputValue));

            // using dynamic arrays in vector allows for multiple input
            //    with no output until all input received
            outPutValues.push_back(new char[8]);

            int decimalValue = ProcessInput(fromBase, toBase, inputValue,
                                            length);

            // if the new base is decimal, simply output decimalValue;
            //    else process the new base and store in an output array;
            ConvertToBase(decimalValue, toBase, outPutValues[count]);

            count++;
        }


        for (int c = 0; c < outPutValues.size(); c++)
        {
            int k(0);
            // display only set values of the output array
            while ((outPutValues[c][k] == '\0') || (outPutValues[c][k] == '0'))
                k++;

            while (k < 8)
            {
                cout << outPutValues[c][k];
                k++;
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // free up dynamic arrays
    for (int d = 0; d < outPutValues.size(); d++)
        delete outPutValues[d];

    return 0;
} // end main

// ProcessInput receives the input array and translates the char values
//    into a decimal value to be returned to calling function
int ProcessInput(const int fromBase, const int toBase, char inputValue[],
                 const int length)
{
    int exponent(0), decimalValue(0);

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        exponent = (length - j - 1);

        // convert inputValue from char to int to be processed into decimal;
        //    negative signs are ignored
        switch (inputValue[j])
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A': decimalValue += (10 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B': decimalValue += (11 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C': decimalValue += (12 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D': decimalValue += (13 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E': decimalValue += (14 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F': decimalValue += (15 * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
            case '-': cout << "Negative Number Received. Converted to unsigned int.\n"; break;
            default:  decimalValue += ((inputValue[j] - '0') * Exponent(fromBase, exponent)); break;
        }
    }
    return decimalValue;
} // end ProcessInput


// ConvertToBase converts the decimal form of a number into
//    a new base by dividing the decimal until 0 and
//    storing the remainders in the output array
void ConvertToBase(int decimal, const int inBase, char outPut[])
{
    int remainder(0);

    // char variable used to convert int back into char
    //    for output
    char intToChar('0');

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        remainder = decimal % inBase;
        decimal /= inBase;

        // account for hex and if remainder is an int,
        //    store as char in output array using char intToChar
        switch (remainder)
        {
            case 10: outPut[i] = 'A'; break;
            case 11: outPut[i] = 'B'; break;
            case 12: outPut[i] = 'C'; break;
            case 13: outPut[i] = 'D'; break;
            case 14: outPut[i] = 'E'; break;
            case 15: outPut[i] = 'F'; break;
            default: for (int j = 0; j < remainder; j++) {intToChar++;}
                outPut[i] = intToChar;
                intToChar = '0';
                break;
        }
    }
}  // end ConvertToBase


// converts input to decimal form by multiplying
//    each number place by its base and exponent
double Exponent(const int number, const int exponent)
{
    double value(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
        value *= number;
    return value;
} // end Exponent
```

Comment: Right off the top, `while (!cin.eof())` isn't the correct way to terminate this while loop.

Comment: Yes the project itself isn't very pretty, but it's a template I have to work off of, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you input more than 7 characters? That will overflow `inputValue`, and there's no way to detect or prevent it. You should use `std::string` instead of a character array.

Comment: It should be a max of 8 though, correct? I input 8 values because they emulate 8 bits. The array is 8 elements in size so that shouldn't overflow, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JeffA. you are missing the trailing `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

> @JeffA. you are missing the trailing \0. – erikced

Yes sir, just saw this right before I saw your answer. I need that extra element for the null terminator. Thanks! I know this project is messy and more C than C++, but the template is what it is. Thanks for all the help guys and gals!